# Chrono Time Counter Issue in C++ Error: No match for operator

Tags: c++, time, operator-keyword, c++-chrono

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

void SieveOfEratosthenes (int n)
{
    bool prime[n+1], flag=true;
    int counter=0, ct=0;
    for (int i =0;i<n+1;i++){
        prime[i]=true;
    }
    for (int p=2; p*p<=n; p++)
    {
        if (prime[p]==true)
        {
            for (int i=p*2; i<=n; i += p)
            {
                prime[i] = false; 
            }
        }
    }
   // Print all prime numbers 
    for (int p=2; p<=n; p++)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
              auto begin=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
        if (prime[p])
        {
              cout << p << " ";
              counter+=1;
              flag=false;
        }
        if(counter==10)
        {
              auto end=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
              auto duration=chrono::nanoseconds(end-begin);
              cout<<"Time elapsed:"<<duration.count();
              counter=0;
              flag=true;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}


int main()
{
     int n;
     cout<<"Type a number:";
     cin>>n;
     cout<<endl<<"Following are the prime numbers smaller or equal to:"<<n<<endl;
     SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
     return 0;
}
// Driver Program to test above function
```

It's an algorithm for finding prime numbers smaller to n(given from keyboard) and i want to get the time every 10 prime numbers found.I am getting operator error and it's on (end-begin).I can't understand where the error is.And i have tried to write the function in a seperate .o file but still got nothing.Any help would be much appreciated.!

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsh6W.png)

Comment: `begin` is out of scope already?

Comment: That was the mistake i was getting before now i am getting this one.Befo

Comment: Please update the title of your question to give readers some idea what you're asking about.

Comment: I compile with c++.

Comment: Add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-warnings` when compiling. It's a start.

Comment: `bool prime[n + 1]` is a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use a `std::vector` instead since `VLA`:s aren't supported by standard C++.

Comment: I had no problem on compiling before i added the functions to count the execution time.

Comment: If you add the options I suggested and deal with the problems reported, your programs will usually be both more portable and stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`begin` is defined inside an `if` block, which can not be accessed by `end-begin`. A simple fix is to move the definition out of the `for`-loop:

```cpp
      decltype(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) begin;                                                                                                                                    
     // Print all prime numbers                                                                                                                                                                
      for (int p=2; p<=n; p++)                                                                                                                                                                 
      {                                                                                                                                                                                        
          if (flag)                                                                                                                                                                            
          {                                                                                                                                                                                    
                begin=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                                                                                                                                    
          }
          // ...
      }
```

**Note** It is usually a bad idea to `using namespace std` globally. Since `begin` collides with `std::begin`, the error message becomes intricate. If you instead write `namespace chrono = std::chrono; using std::cout;`, the error would become more clear:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void SieveOfEratosthenes(int)’:
test.cpp:41:53: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘std::begin’?
   41 |               auto duration=chrono::nanoseconds(end-begin);
      |                                                     ^~~~~
      |                                                     std::begin
```